# How can i call a function that return a BOOLEAN using MyBatis?

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, mybatis, plsqldeveloper

i'm using MyBatis to call a function in a PL SQL database. The function have one of the OUT parameter as BOOLEAN like this:

```
FUNCTION f_foo_function(foo IN VARCHAR, foo_output OUT BOOLEAN, error OUT VARCHAR2)
```

My problem is when i try to call the function from my xml mapper, every try i do mybatis don't recognize the boolean output and throw me and error like incompatible types. Also when i try to test the function from PLSQL Developer it make a convertion like this 
`:pout_boolean_result := sys.diutil.bool_to_int(pout_boolean_result);`
and return me the boolean as a bit.

**It is posible to ignore that integer and specify MyBatis to treat the ouput as a boolean? How can i do that?**

My xml is something like this:

```
<select id="getFooFunction" statementType="CALLABLE">
        {#{result, mode=OUT, jdbcType=INTEGER} = call f_foo_function
        (
            #{foo, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
            #{foo_output, mode=OUT, jdbcType=DOUBLE},
            #{error, mode=OUT, jdbcType=VARCHAR}
        )
        }
</select>
```

Comment: What version of Oracle is your database? As I recall, 11g's JDBC driver had no concept of boolean types

Comment: Please add the actual error that you get to the question

Comment: Functions with OUT parameters are bad practice, not least because we can't use them in SELECT statements. Functions should just return (as in keyword RETURN) a value. Furthermore Oracle SQL does not support BOOLEAN datatype. Hence SYS.DIUTIL.BOOL_TO_INT(). I'm afraid you'll need to rewrite your function so it conforms to Oracle SQL rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test it, I defined the function as follows.

```sql
create or replace function f_foo_function(
  foo in varchar, 
  foo_output out integer, 
  error out varchar2
) return integer is
begin
    foo_output := 1;
    error := 'No error';
  return 99;
end;
```

`foo_output` is defined as `INTEGER` as `BOOLEAN` is invalid as APC pointed out.

The mapper method is defined as...

```java
void getFooFunction(FooFuncParam param);
```

The parameter is a POJO.

```java
public class FooFuncParam {
  private Integer result;
  private String foo;
  private boolean fooOutput;
  private String error;
  // getters/setters
}
```

And here is the mapper statement.

```xml
<update id="getFooFunction" statementType="CALLABLE">
  {#{result,jdbcType=INTEGER,mode=OUT} = call f_foo_function(
    #{foo,mode=IN},
    #{fooOutput,jdbcType=INTEGER,javaType=_boolean,mode=OUT}, 
    #{error,jdbcType=VARCHAR,mode=OUT})}
</update>
```

Note that `javaType` is specified to convert `INTEGER` to `boolean`.
If the function sets `0` to `foo_output`, `false` is set to `FooFuncParam.fooOutput`.
And non-zero value means `true`. If necessary, you can write a custom type handler to change the behavior.

Here is an executable [demo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-58205549) tested with Oracle 18c and ojdbc 19.3.0.0.

Comment: This answer works fine for me, thanks! But what happen if you don't have access to modify the function in the database and is defined as BOOLEAN? Is there any handler of MyBatis to map the response?

Comment: Glad to know it worked. The thing is, there does not seem to be `BOOLEAN` type in Oracle. Is it a user defined type or something? Anyway, if the built-in [BooleanTypeHandler](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/ibatis/type/BooleanTypeHandler.java) does not work, it's fairly easy to write a custom type handler. In that case, you may need to specify `typeHandler` instead of `javaType` in the parameter reference.