# Correctly configuring MyBatis OUT parameter to stored procedure call

Tags: mysql, mybatis

I a working on a legacy application which uses **MyBatis**. The DB is **MySql**.

A stored procedure has been added, with an **OUT** parameter to get the value of a flag set within the procedure.The issue is that while to call to the procedure is working and setting the value of the OUT parameter, that value is not being returned to Java.

This is the Java definition of the method call in the mapper interface.

```
void update(@Param("param1") Integer param1, @Param("param2") String param2, 
@Param("param3") String param3, @Param("successFlag") Boolean successFlag);
```

This is the definition of the update function in the MyBatis XML mapper file:

```
<update id="update" parameterType="map" statementType="CALLABLE">
   {call UPDATE__PROC(
   #{param1, mode=IN, jdbcType=INTEGER},
   #{param2, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
   #{param3, mode=IN, jdbcType=VARCHAR},
   #{successFlag, mode=OUT, jdbcType=BOOLEAN}
   )}
</update>
```

This is how the MyBatis update is being called from the DAO:

```
Boolean successFlag = false; 
try {
   session.getMapper(myMapper.class).update(param1, param2, param3, successFlag);
} catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error(e.getMessage());
}       
logger.info("successFlag: "+successFlag);
return successFlag;
```

Can anyone assist? Thanks

Comment: `update()` should take a `Map` as a parameter. The OUT param will be set to the `Map`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7845399/). It's also possible to use POJO. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58221626/).

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot. Realized that what I was doing was obviously wrong anyway because boolean is passeded by reference so would never have got updated.